# Запросы php и mysql

Tags: mysql, php, sql

Добрый день! Возник такой вопрос, как реализовать запрос. Есть таблицы с пользователями и предметами, нужно сделать так, чтобы при  запросе проверялось есть ли пользователь в базе. Если есть, то выводить список имеющихся у него предметов, а если нет, то добавить его в базу. Как мне правельно это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM 'users' WHERE 'name'='$username' ");
if (mysql_num_rows($result)) {
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['items'] . "<br>";
  }
} else {
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'users' (name, items) VALUES ('ololol', 'trololo')");
}
```

Comment: Что то с этой строчкой мне не все понятно
if ($result = mysql_fetch_array($query))
выдает ошибку
Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Comment: изменил код, проверь.

Comment: Все рано ошибка Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given 
А разве в условии можно присваевать????

Comment: угу, убери это присвоение(поправил код)

Comment: Большое спасибо заработало

Comment: Не за что, обращайтесь.

Answer (score 0):

$q=mysql_query("select * from <таблица> where <Что тебе нужно>=Бнайти>");

<> - убери с запроса.